# Counting items by different conditions in rows in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix

I am trying to create a confusion matrix of an experiment.

So the dataset is like this;

```
    Responses   Condition
3    1             R
4    1             R
6    1             R
7    1             R
8   -1             R
9   -1             N
10  -1             N
11  -1             N
12  -1             R
13   1             R
```

I want to categorize four different conditions; and I want to count each one of the conditions.

1 & N,
-1 & N,
 1 & R,
-1 & R

I want to count each one of those situations in the dataframe.

I have tried to use .itertuples , but I don't know how to use it with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['Condition','Responses']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
Condition  Responses
N          -1           3
            1           0
R          -1           2
            1           5
dtype: int64
```

Or

```
pd.crosstab(df.Condition,df.Responses)
Responses  -1   1
Condition        
N           3   0
R           2   5
```

Answer (score 1):

this could work

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Conditions":["R","R","N","N"], "Responses":[1,-1,-1,-1]})
df.groupby(["Conditions","Responses"]).apply(len).to_frame("occurrences")
```